# Can I restart an exchange mailbox migration that permanently stalled?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

I am migrating from Google G Suite to Office365. Most of the mailboxes migrated just fine. But one very large one stalled out.  It got to 95% complete. That took 3 days.

Is there any way that I can restart the migration so it picks up where it left off?

Can I just start it again?  Or will that duplicate everything?

Answer (score 1):

I have not done too many IMAP migrations.  If you connect to Exchange Online in Powershell can you list out your move requests?

If yes - you should be able to see a detailed message

```
Get-MoveRequest 'name of user' | Get-MoveRequestStatistics
```

And potentially restart it

```
Get-MoveRequest 'name of user' | Resume-MoveRequest
```

If you can only use the MigrationBatch commands, you can attempt to use the Start-MigrationBatch or complete-MigrationBatch commands.

If your able, review the detailed message to understand why it stopped on it's own and if there is something you need to fix before restarting. In some cases, the move request just can't be completed and you will be forced to re-migrate that user.